# convert mysql timestamp to mktime

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, mktime

I have the following MySQL timestamp:
2009-06-23 16:21:48
How can I convert it to a format like mktime()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a MySQL function [`unix_timestamp`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp).  In your SQL query, instead of selecting the Datetime or Timestamp column directly, do this:

```
SELECT unix_timestamp(MyDatetimeColumn) FROM MyTable
```

Alternatively, if you have the string already, you could use the PHP function [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Comment: You probably want to alias the name too: SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MyDatetimeColumn) AS MyTimestampColumn

Comment: where should i preform the calculation in order to maximize efficiency? at the PHP or at the MySQL level?

Comment: The SQL implementation is probably faster because it doesn't have to parse a string.

Answer (score 1):

ok,
I was wrestling with this for a week (longer but i took a break from it).

I have two specific fields in tables

```
creationDate > timestamp > current_timestamp
editDate > timestamp > current_timestamp
```

they were pulling out either dec 31 1969, or just nothing... 
annoying... 
very annoying

in mysql query i did:

```
                unix_timestamp(creationDate) AS creationDate
                unix_timestamp(editDate) AS editDate
```

in php convert i did:

```
        $timestamp = $result_ar['creationDate'];
        $creationDate = date("Y-M-d (g:i:s a)", $timestamp)
                echo($creationDate);

        $editstamp = $result_ar['editDate'];
        $editDate = date("Y-M-d (g:i:s a)", $editstamp)
                echo($editDate);
```

this solved my problem for me returning

```
                2010-Jun-28 (5:33:39 pm)
                2010-Jun-28 (12:09:46 pm)
```

respectively.

I hope this helps someone out...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [strtotime](http://hr.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function.