# Extract the Day / Month / Year from a Timestamp on MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp

I have :

```
$date = $actualite['date'];
```

`$actualite['date']` is a TIMESTAMP

And I was wondering **how can I extract from this timestamp** the day, then the month, then the year in 3 variables.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Possible Dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064075/convert-mysql-timestamp-to-mktime http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303724/formating-an-sql-timestamp-with-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238071/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-format-a-timestamp-from-sql-in-php

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `date_parse($actualite['date']);`, which will return an array containing the day, month, year and other items.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php

Example:

```
<?php
print_r(date_parse("2006-12-12 10:00:00.5"));
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [year] => 2006
    [month] => 12
    [day] => 12
    [hour] => 10
    [minute] => 0
    [second] => 0
    [fraction] => 0.5
    [warning_count] => 0
    [warnings] => Array()
    [error_count] => 0
    [errors] => Array()
    [is_localtime] => 
)
```

Comment: `list($year, $month, $day) = array_values(date_parse("2006-12-22 10:00:00"));`

Answer (score 13):

You can extract the values directly within your MySQL query

```
SELECT DAY( <TIMESTAMP_FIELD> ) AS DAY, 
       MONTH( <TIMESTAMP_FIELD> ) AS MONTH, 
       YEAR( <TIMESTAMP_FIELD> ) AS YEAR
FROM <TABLE>
```

Comment: @Kermani - I know what he said he wanted, I'm suggesting an _alternative_ method to achieve the same goal

Comment: @Kermani His solution works as requested and fine with a field in a mysql table which has the type TIMESTAMP as requested. The question is not correct. The questioner asks for a MYSQL solution but shows PHP-code.

Answer (score 1):

Another way with more options for formatting would be:

```
$date = date_create($myTimeStamp); // From database "2020-04-09 17:59:20"
$formatedDate = date_format($date, "d/m/y"); // --> 09/04/20
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

It might be less intuitive than `date_parse()` but gives you more options as far as I can see.